# How to get action performed after clicking on multiple correct drawings?

Tags: android, onclick, action, draw, android-canvas

I am trying to develop an application it follows as below.

Presently, at each time my canvas shows a circle and if you click the recently shown circle the user will be lead to next level.  If user clicks not on the recent one the application closes.

Now my requirement is,  I would like to draw two circles at each time at different locations on the canvas and the user has to click on the recently shown TWO circles.  After clicking on those two circles only the action should be performed depending on whether the clicks are correct or wrong.  But the action is being perfromed just only after clicking on one circle.  But i want the control to wait untill i complete clicking on both,.i.e., two circles and then act accordingly.

can any one help in this regard....?
please.
Thank you in advance for your help...!

Comment: Your question is confusing , you have two circles with two distinct functions, why take two inputs?

Comment: i don't want to give inputs, just i want to perform MouseClick operation on those two circles.  When i complete clicking on both circles then the action should be performed.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a structure for storing which circles have been selected, and which not.
Then, in your actionPerformed, you check if all the circles are selected before going to the next level.

Hope it helps :)

Otherwise post some code.